# What does this pattern of voltages in my electrical outlet mean?

Tags: electrical, wiring

I plugged in one of those three-light outlet testers, and got a strange result:  the red light was dim, one yellow light was bright, and the other yellow light was dim.

So I got out my trusty multimeter and measured the actual voltages.  They came up in this confusing pattern:

```
Hot-Neu = 117V
Hot-Gnd =  60V
Neu-Gnd =  57V
```

My understanding is that I should be seeing negligible voltage on neu-gnd and full or nearly full voltage on hot-gnd.

How on earth am I getting half and half like that?  (And are my devices and/or personal well-being in danger?)

---

## Update 1:

### The panel

After prying loose the umpteen-times-painted-over cover and vacuuming out most of the crud, here is the fuse panel with the guts exposed:

[image: Fuse box]

As you can see, I've replaced the four Edison-type fuses with drop-in-replacement circuit breakers.  The top two heavy ones remain actual fuses.

The vertical bus bar at top center seems to be ground — you can see a bare wire connected to the third screw (as well as a heavy white neutral wire to the second).  There is also a curious thinner solid bare wire at bottom left, buried behind everything, that comes out of a tiny hole in the bottom side of the box and goes back into it, after looping up and loosely touching the bottom vertical bar.  I'm not sure it's actually connected to anything through that hole; at least, pulling on it a bit doesn't meet with any opposition, the way all the other wires going out of the box do.

The vertical bus bar at the bottom seems to be neutral, as you can see various white wires connected to it.  (Though some of them are dingy enough that they hardly look white any more.)  There seems to be continuity from the top to the bottom bar, though, so it could be that that's one continuous piece of metal.

Voltage between those two bars is 0V.  Between each pair of big fuse lugs is 234V.  From the top bar to each of the inner lugs is 117V, and from the top bar to each outer lug is 115V.  These voltages seem to carry straight through to the lugs below each of the four smaller circuit breakers.  Same voltages apply all around if you go from the neutral bar instead of the ground bar.

So, as far as I can tell, nothing voltage-wise is out of order in the fuse box.

### Other outlets

It's something of a mixed bag.  An outlet on the opposite side of the wall from the one I originally tested above, a few inches away, in the bedroom, has 117/39/31; another further along in there has 117/20/7; another in the original (living) room has 117/11/14; one in the dining room has 117/7/11; one in the kitchen has 117/0/117 (simple hot and neutral reversed!  Tester says the same); one in the utility room says 117/117/0 (normal).

Comment: Is this happening on one receptacle, some receptacles or all receptacles?

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact Added more info in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the pictures, you have a problem of receptacles that have ground pins but no actual ground wire! That should never happen* but if someone decides "I need a 3-wire receptacle to plug in my new stuff, but I don't have any so I'll just add one", that is what happens.

* Except for GFCI in lieu of ground.

If you open up the problem receptacles, you will find black & white wires coming into the box but no ground wire. If you have a ground wire and it is just not connected, you can connect and it should solve the problem for that receptacle. But more likely you just don't have the ground wires, because they weren't required when your house was built.

There are two solutions:

- Retrofit Ground

This is what Harper is referring to. You can add ground wires separately from the hot/neutral wires, either going all the way back to your panel or to the nearest same-or-larger ground wire in another circuit (as long as it goes back to the same panel).

- GFCI in lieu of ground

Despite the name a Ground Fault Circuit Interrupter does not actually need *ground* to do its job. It can work quite well without ground. That means you can install a GFCI receptacle without ground and get both safety (thanks to the GFCI) and a *legitimate* ground pin (thanks to the receptacle). That ground pin does not actually function any better than your existing floating ground pin. But if there is an imbalance that *would* have gone on the ground pin, the GFCI will trip and solve the immediate problem (and possibly save your life). Any such GFCI receptacles do have to be marked to indicate that they don't have an actual ground, because there are some devices where the ground is also used to handle static electricity discharge or other things. But for pure safety, that will do the job.

---

*This original answer was based on having ground wires everywhere but a problem at the panel. That is not the case for OP, but leaving below for future reference as it can be valid in some situations.*

The answer below is assuming that *all* receptacles in your house have the same problem. If the problem is limited to one receptacle then it is a problem at that receptacle (check the ground wire in that box). If the problem is limited to all receptacles on one circuit then it is likely a problem at either the panel (ground wire for that circuit) or the first receptacle in that circuit.

**Bad Neutral-Ground Bond**

There are a **lot** of messages about how/why/when/where ground and neutral are to be bonded (connected) together. TL;DR Should be exactly one place, either main panel or at a disconnect or other box before the main panel, but there are many subpanels with a neutral-ground bond either grandfathered or by mistake.

In your case you are **missing** that bond. This is a potentially (pun intended) dangerous situation, because if you have a fault such as a hot to the metal case of an appliance, it will not trip a breaker as quickly as it should, if at all.

**Check your main panel.** If you don't know what you are looking at, remove the front cover (carefully!) and take pictures showing all the wires, breakers and neutral & ground bars. Ideally, there should be a screw connecting the neutral bar to the panel, but the connection can also be via a wire. It is nearly impossible that it was installed this way, so that should mean either a screw came loose or a wire came out, possibly due to corrosion, possibly as a side effect of other work done improperly.

Comment: Added more info in the question.

Comment: It appears to be an open ground. Something is leaking to it. Check your ground, it appears it was wired with #?/2 without ground. This could start a fire as well as a shock hazard.

Comment: Hrm.  Indeed, I opened both that second living-room outlet and the utility-room one, and neither one have a ground wire.  Not sure why they vary as they do, even to the point where the utility-room one seems completely correct.  The truly confusing thing is that I replaced a pair of switches in the garage with a two-switch+two-outlet configuration, and that junction box _did_ have a ground wire, despite all the hardware seeming exactly as ancient as the rest!  Not sure what the heck to do now, given that this place is a rental…

Comment: *given that this place is a rental* Shh! You weren't supposed to say that, because you aren't supposed to do *any* electrical work on your own in a rental. As far as the ground problem, it is quite common for circuits to be added or replaced over the years, and any that were added after grounds were required (or at least after NM cable included ground as standard) will have ground. Looking at your fuse panel, *some* of your circuits have ground and some don't. Any circuit that doesn't have ground will have *unpredictable* values for the hot-ground and neutral-ground depending on the wiring.

Answer (score 1):

Congrats on using a 3-light tester *correctly* on old work, by looking at the lights and disregarding the label altogether. (the label's advice is designed for *mistakes* in new construction, not *failures* in wiring that was correct.)

Well, here is how a 3-light tester is wired.

[image]

I'll fast-forward you to the end of the story: Consider what happens if ground is ***gone***.  The two outer lights *are now in series with each other* across hot and neutral.

That's it.  That is indicating you don't have a ground.

Now given that you are seeing voltages, it's possible that this is a circuit *extension* and the extension was done with grounded wires connected *within the extension* but not back to the service panel.  (the ancient thing may not even have a proper Grounding Electrode System).

That would explain the "midpoint voltage" -- the ground wire is being *capacitively coupled* to the adjacent hot and neutral wires in equal proportion. Cheapo DVMs contain so little actual hardware that it makes them fairly sensitive, and they can see this phantom voltage.  An analog meter would not see that capacitive coupling; there's just not enough electro-motive force there to move the needle.

Having an "Island of grounds" not connected back to the panel is Super Bad.  Without the connection back to the Grounding Electrode System, the ground wires cannot do their safety jobs.  In fact, all they do is **distribute ground faults** among the equipment on the island.  So if one develops a hot-ground fault that electrifies its chassis, now all the equipment and wiring on the island also has its grounds energized. Great!

It is a Code violation to extend wiring off an ungrounded circuit, and now you can see why.

In 2014 they greatly liberalized the rules to **retrofit ground**. You should make full use of this new permission to distribute real ground where needed, and to "render safe" any islands of grounds.